# Is it okay to have the submit button in a form when using ajax if you're returning false?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, button, submit

This code below takes the input from a form and grabs the result from a handler. This emails sends and works properly; however, could my code not be correct because I have the submit button instead of a button? I figured it would be ok because I'm returning false in the click function. Maybe using the button value would be a better idea and taking out the action in the form since it's already in the ajax?

```
<div id="result">
</div>
<form action="handler.php" id="contact-form">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="clear">
    <input type="text" class="clear">
    <textarea name="message" class="clear">
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit-form">
</form>
```

```
$("#submit-form").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "handler.php",
        data: $("#contact-form").serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            $('#result').html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: What if user presses Enter key while on one of the input's.. That will not trigger your click handler, but submit your form as usual to handler.php.

Comment: @pXL Ah I see, I just tried submitting the form on enter, but everything still worked as usual instead of going to handler because I have something echoed out in handler. If it went to the handler, it would have been a blank page with a paragraph; instead, I am getting the result with ajax. Is this just a browser thing?

Answer (score 1):

The form can be sumbited not only by clicking the submit button, but by also pressing the `Enter` key while focused on an input type text or by typing in the console something like: `document.forms['your_form'].submit();`. Therefore, you must add the event on the form element, like this:

```
$("#your_form_id").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;

    // your code here

    return false;
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I will do this from now on!